# Inconsistent inference of union types for identical conditional return values

Tags: typescript

I've encountered an inconsistency in TypeScript's type inference when using with conditional return values in functions. I have two identical functions, register and register2, as shown below:

```
const register = (step: 1 | 2) => {
    if (step === 1) {
        return {
            otp: "",
        };
    }
    return {
        userId: "",
    };
};

const register2 = (step: 1 | 2) => {
    if (step === 1) {
        const res = {
            otp: "",
        };
        return res;
    }
    const res = {
        userId: "",
    };
    return res;
};
```

Both functions return objects with the same structure based on the value of the step argument. However, TypeScript infers different return types for these two functions.

`register` returns a union type: `{ otp: string; userId?: undefined; } | { userId: string; otp?: undefined; }`

`register2` returns a union type: `{ otp: string; } | { userId: string; }`

**Use Case**

```
const user = register(1);
if (user.otp) {
    // **
} else {
    // **
}
```

This works fine

```
const user2 = register2(1);
if (user2.otp) {
    // **
} else {
    // **
}
```

Here `user2.otp` error:
Property 'otp' does not exist on type '{ otp: string; } | { userId: string; }

Ofcourse this can be solved by using `"otp" in user2` but this is not typesafe as 1st case
because otp can be renamed or may never in response

I want
**Return the same type from register2 as the return type of register without writing explicitly**

Comment: Please [edit] the post to ask a single well-defined question.  Is it "Why does TypeScript infer different types in these cases, even though the underlying code logic is the same?"  Or is it "how can I return the same type from register2 as the return type of register without writing explicitly?"  Or is it "how can I create a type generic which converts ... to ... where these return types will be dynamic"?  Right now those look like three related but distinct questions which require different answers and somewhat independent efforts.  I'd be happy to answer any one of them, but not three.

Comment: want i really want _Return the same type from register2 as the return type of register without writing explicitly_ but i can't find an answer for this anywhere even with the help of chatgpt. So i asked _how can I create a type generic which converts ... to ... where these return types will be dynamic_. Please answer any of these 2

Comment: "any of these 2" means the question isn't focused enough and might be closed.  Please [edit] the question to ask just one of them.  If the first one is not possible then that's what the answer will be (and I think it might not be possible).  If you want to ask about your potential utility type workaround then ask that only.  I'll check back once this is done.

Comment: @jcalz i updated the question as you said please answer i really need this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, unfortunately.  I'm could write up an answer saying so but it might not be worth either of our time.  Maybe someone will come up with a clever way to do this.

Comment: *can be solved by using "otp" in user2 but this is not typesafe as 1st case because otp can be renamed or may never in response* -- doesn't make sense.  If that's your problem you should list 3 cases - `opt in`, `userIdx in`, and `else /* error*/`

Answer (score 0):

Is using [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) an option for you ? This might enforce the return type, given you know you can only have 2 possible values as a parameter.

I know it doesn't fix the inference issue, but I think this is something due to the fact that even if the variable is a const, an object can still have additional properties added, that the static analyser is not capable to see.

See the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYHMYGcquQCh1QAcAuRARgEpyBvROKMxHZGMdRAXwFgAoUJFgIUGbLgJFmAJhqJ6ILHgCSAE3Kt2nXgPDR4SNJiKTczCogA+iWfP6JEMYIkJnEAXk+Uqdvg4doUCDISLT2-g6MzABE0QA04Q5cANzhOgGoQSG+EYoq6oixCX7cqXwp-PwQCDiIecgeosYS+NRlAPTtEQB6APyI1WC19XQMTBpQbBzcVTVQdUrI0o1G4njSrVQdXYPDi9KjURNT2rND8-UAzCtiJhuy2wNzC+uj9WrHWjN8lbpCBk01ktXCRyNRDuMWJMvjpBPoRKs7iCZHIFIsPlCTt84cJDLcJBspGCrDYfGESk4XFIPF5qDl-Lt5mgsI1yRFIpCiolStzAsE8VgyklwozRCz3PSHO8ClyShUSnzssyyikgA)

```ts
function register(step: 1): { otp: string }
function register(step: 2): { userId: string }
function register(step: 1 | 2) {
  if (step === 1) {
    return {
      otp: "",
    };
  }
  return {
    userId: "",
  };
};

const user = register(1);
//    ^? const user: { otp: string }
const user2 = register2(1);
// const user2: { otp: string }
const user3 = register2(2);
// const user2: { userId: string }


function register2(step: 1): { otp: string }
function register2(step: 2): { userId: string }
function register2(step: 1 | 2) {
  if (step === 1) {
    const res = {
      otp: "",
    };
    return res;
  }
  const res = {
    userId: "",
  };
  return res;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but i said `return types will be dynamic.` in the last of the question but your solution is for current situation. Also i can't use function overloading.